# Git Flow: How to keep master log clean?

Tags: git, git-flow

I've started git flow and loved it for many reasons. However, one of our primary goal is to keep the master branch log very clean. We just want to see each released log in master branch (that means when we finish a release the commit log should be in the master).

Please see the output of `git log` or `git log master` in master branch`

> ```
> Merge branch 'release/r1'
>
>
> release bug fixed
>
>
> feature 3 done
>
>
> feature 2 done
>
>
> feature 1 done
>
>
> Initial commit ~
> ```

what we want to see here are: 'initial commit' and 'merge branch release/r1'. we don't want to see the commit log that are done in feature or release branch.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a framework which allows you to plug all kind of controls on the commit, in order for you to enforce policies when said commits are done on the master branch.

If you have one "blessed" repo, you can add **[gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite)** on the server of that repo, and add [VREFs](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html): small hooks that will be triggered on each push.